# LXC setup with multiple LVM-backed disks

Tags: lvm, lxc

I'd like to set up an lxc container on an ubuntu host with multiple back-end disks.  At least two:

```
/boot
/
/opt, maybe
```

Is there a way to, in one lxc-setup command, to accomplish this?  Below is what I"ve curently been using to create containers:

```
sudo lxc-create -t ubuntu -n ubuntu32 -B lvm --vgname=lxcDG --lvname=lv-lxc-ubuntu32 \
    --fstype=ext4 --fssize=5G -- -a i386
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having need similar to your's.

I think I found a solution but **not** with a single command:

Assuming your lxc container already exists and is located in /var/lib/lxc/mycontainer/, 
you'll find a file named fstab, probably empty. Assuming you created a logical volume named lv, in the volume group vg0, ext3 formated, and you want to use it in your container. Add the following line:

```
/dev/vg0/lv mnt ext3 defaults 0 0
```

Try to start your container:

```
lxc-start -n mycontainer -F
```

Log in and check you see and access some files contained in lv (if not, mount your volume in the host, create a file and unmount it, before starting the container).